# How do I remove items from an array that only contain a string?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to find a method that allows me to remove items from an array that contain a certain string. Example, from the array below, I want to remove any items that contain the string 'pages'.

```
[
  'pages/404',
  '_app',
  '_document',
  'admin',
  'browse',
  'pages/campaigns/tcitp',
  'cause-chemistry',
  'pages/cause-chemistry/results',
  'cause/',
  'causes',
  'pages/donation-widget',
  'index'
]
```

Comment: `newArray = oldArray.filter(s => !s.includes('pages'));`

Answer (score 1):

```
[
  'pages/404',
  '_app',
  '_document',
  'admin',
  'browse',
  'pages/campaigns/tcitp',
  'cause-chemistry',
  'pages/cause-chemistry/results',
  'cause/',
  'causes',
  'pages/donation-widget',
  'index'
].filter(x => x.indexOf('pages') === -1)
```